# Can I push data directly to Kibana's data store when using the ELK stack?

Tags: redis, elastic-stack

(a very similar question has been asked but has no answers)

I have a job processor (node.js) that takes in a couple of fields, runs a query and data manipulation on the result then sends the final result out to RabbitMQ queue. I have logging set up with Bunyan.

Now we'd like to log the results. A typical record in this log would look like:

```
{
"queryTime": 1460135319890,
"transID": "d5822210-8f87-4327-b43c-957b1ff96306", 
"customerID": "AF67879",
"processingTime": 2345,
"queryStartDate": "1/1/2016", 
"queryEndDate": "1/5/2016" 
"numRecords": 20, 
"docLength": 67868
}
```

The org has an existing ELK stack set up. I've got enough experience with Redis that it would be very simple to just push the data that I want out to the Redis instance in the ELK stack. Seems a lot easier than setting up logstash and messing around with its config.

I'd like to be able to visualize the customerID, processingTime and numRecords fields (to start). Is Kibana the right choice for this? Can I push data directly to it instead of messing around with LogStash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana doesn't have a datastore of its own and it relies on the datastore of Elasticsearch,i.e. Kibana uses the data stored in Elasticsearch to provide visualizations.

Hence you cannot directly push redis logs into Kibana by bypassing elasticsearch. For parsing logs from redis you need to use Logstash & Elasticsearch to push in your data.

Approach: Use Logstash and create a logstash configuration file wherein input will contain redis plugin. Output will contain elasticsearch plugin.

**Kibana is an open source-tool which seems to be good in sync with what you want to achieve & also in sync with your organization setup as well.**

Comment: OK then why not just push data directly to Elastic? Why do I need logstash at all? I'm not logging the data, seems silly to write this data to a log just so logstash can read it in.

Comment: Earlier as per design, there were rivers available which put data directly into elasticsearch. However those rivers were deprecated as they caused few cluster issues. 
Reference Link:- https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers

Most of the rivers have been moved into Logstash Input plugins.

Answer (score 0):

We provide native support for node.js so you could push data directly, bypassing Logstash.

(disclosure - I'm an evangelist at Logz.io)

Comment: I gave logz.io about 10s to load and it wouldn't. Not a good sign.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Perhaps connectivity? We have literally hundreds of people connected with sub-second response time so would love to hear more about your experience...